# Combining 2 numpy 3d arrays into overall shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 3d np.arrays containing numbers.
both np.arrays can have different shapes (different dimensions).

my objective would be to generate a 3d np.array:

- which have a shape which contain both other shapes (ie (1,1,3) & (1,2,1) => (1,2,3))
- where each element is the sum of the element of the parent 3d array which have the same coordinates (assuming 0 when the coordinates did not exist)

to summarize, I would like to obtain the following:

```
a=np.array([[[0, 0, 0, 1]]])
b= np.array([[[0],
        [1]]])
addition(a, b)
>>> array([[[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I found better

```py
def addition(a,b):
    c = np.zeros(np.max([np.shape(a), np.shape(b)], axis=0), dtype=int)
    c[np.where(a!=0)] += a[np.where(a!=0)]
    c[np.where(b!=0)] += b[np.where(b!=0)]
    return c
```

OLD:

> After multiple research, i haven’t found a good way to do it without
> iterate over all of the array :
>
> ```py
> def addition(a, b):
>     c = np.zeros(np.max([np.shape(a), np.shape(b)], axis=0), dtype=int)
>     for index, element in np.ndenumerate(a):
>         c[index] += element
>     for index, element in np.ndenumerate(b):
>         c[index] += element
>     return c
> ```
>
> I’ll continue to search a better way to do it
> EDIT 2:

I added a dtype=int, because you seem to want to keep the int version instead of the float.

Have fun

Comment: I have another solution that i found better

Comment: That's great. Thank you very much !